# Python - extract the 3rd item from a list?

Tags: python

I have a list as per below, it is currently returning the first and the 3rd item in the list, but i only want the 3rd item not the 3rd, how can i achieve this?

```
>>>list = ['1', '2', '3', '45']
>>>print list[::2]
['1', '3']
```

Thanks

Comment: Just `list[2]`? Also, do not name your variable `list`, this is built-in name.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=list#typesseq-common

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please, can you try it?:

```
print list[2]
```